# How do you use handler form another script

Tags: applescript, handler

In AppleScript how do you use a handler from another script?

I have tried this

```
set test to (load script "/Users/username/Desktop/test.scpt")

test()
```

here is test.scpt on the desktop

```
display dialog "test"
```

when running the first script I get

error "«script» doesn’t understand the test message." number -1708 from «script» to «class test»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the code you want to call in a handler:

test.scpt:

```
on doTest()
    display dialog "test"
end doTest
```

Then to execute it:

```
set test to (load script "/Users/username/Desktop/test.scpt")
tell test to doTest()
```